# pipenv version 2020.6.2 unable to install some packages? pip3 is able to install same package pipenv can''t?

Tags: python, pipenv, python-cffi

I would love to use pipenv but two packages are causing problems for me?
There appears to be several similar posts over past 2+ years with no real answer  I could find.
I got the latest version of pipenv (2020.6.2) and am asking for install latest package for cffi (1.14.1).

`enter code here`(see example below)

**# pipenv version**

pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2020.6.2

**# Outside of pipenv with pip3 everyting is working**

pip3 install cffi==1.14.1

```
Requirement already satisfied: cffi==1.14.1 in /home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi==1.14.1) (2.20)
```

**Example of problem:**

**pipenv install cffi==1.14.1**

```
Error:  An error occurred while installing cffi==1.14.1!
Error text:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs as _appdirs
ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pip._vendor' (/home/john/.local/share/virtualenvs/06-Login-Auth-HAdzgzLT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```